# easy to use svn tool

Tags: svn, windows-7, google-code

I'm looking for a easy way to sync my local files with Google Code via SVN, since I'm totally new to using SVN I have no clue how to start it properly.

I just want everything that I program locally to be uploaded to google code when I hit synchronize or something.

Comment: And what OS? Quite often that makes a difference!!!

Comment: @David edited post; need it for Windows 7

Comment: Sounds like you want TortoiseSVN which is an Explorer shell extension. You'll still have to get to grips with how SVN works, repositories etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ToirtoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) is one of the more popular. It integrates with Windows Explorer.

The first thing you need to do is Download the code, in a Process calling Check-Out.

There is a good overview of this on the TSVN website : http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html